# Angular 7 - sequential http calls not working (pipe, map)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have searched and searched but cannot find an answer to this one :-(. I am sure the solution is something to do with ConcatMap or similar, but I am getting soooo confused. Here is my code:

```js
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    const body = new HttpParams()
        .set('email', email)
        .set('password', password);

        return this.http.post<User>(LOGINSERVER, body.toString(),
        {
          headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user && user.accessToken) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);

// now go get second set of credentials, the CloudCredentials using the bearer token returned by the first call
                this.http.get<CloudCredential[]>(CLOUDSERVER,
                {
                  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken)
                })
                .pipe(map(credentials => {
                    if (credentials) {
                        localStorage.setItem('cloudCredentials', JSON.stringify(credentials));
                        this.cloudCredentialsSubject.next(credentials);
                    }
                }));
    
                    
            }
            return user;
        }));
    }
```

So whats happening is that the *first* http call to LOGINSERVER works! Great :-) However when that call completes the Chrome debugger shows the line making the *second* http call to CLOUDSERVER being executed, but that API endpoint is never actually run. The .pipe.map() dealing with the second result set line above never gets called/executed.

My overall aim is for the login() method above to return an observable of "User" and also for the method to set local variables currentUserSubject and cloudCredentialsSubject the values of those observables such that they can be referenced later from the rest of the app.

So the question is: why is the *second* http call not being made even though I can see the line of code being executed? What do I need to do to have the second http call execute if and only if the first call succeeds?

Comment: That's because you don't `return` it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax :

```
return this.http.post<User>(LOGINSERVER, body.toString(), { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') }).pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user && user.accessToken) {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.currentUserSubject.next(user);

      return this.http.get<CloudCredential[]>(CLOUDSERVER, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken) }).pipe(
        tap(credentials => {
          if (credentials) {
            localStorage.setItem('cloudCredentials', JSON.stringify(credentials));
            this.cloudCredentialsSubject.next(credentials);
          }
        })
      );
    } else {
      return throwError('User is not defined or has no access Token');
    }
  })
);
```

`map` is used to transform the value of your stream, while `switchMap` is used to switch your stream with another one. `tap` is used to make an operation that doesn't modify the stream. `throwError` throws an error that can then be caught with the `catchError` operator : it doesn't throw an error *per se*, but rather allows you to switch your valid stream to an invalid one, going into the second callback of your `subscribe` function.

You can find all information about the operators here : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/

Learning RxJS takes time, and the best way to start is always the documentation !

Comment: If you get confused by the map/vs [Switch|Concat|Flat|Merge]Map - there is a simple rule of thumb:

inside a map zu should return the value, you want your outer Observble to emit.

inside a higher order Observable like switchMap you should return another Observable, that will emit the value you are looking for.

never subscribe to anything inside a pipe()/subcribe()

Comment: So in your case: you needed the value of the second http-Call so you should return it -> so you need to use a switchMap.

If you dont know which higherOrder Operator to choose: switchMap will work in allmost every case. Try it out here: https://rxmarbles.com/#switchMap

Comment: @tricheriche you are a star! Will mark as answer if I can just get it to compile. The inner http call in your sample:

 return this.http.get<CloudCredential[]>(CLOUDSERVER, ...)

Is causing compilation error "Type Observable<{}> is not assignable to type Observable<User>". I think that's because my method signature is: 

login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User>

So the switchmap seems to be trying to return an observable of a type other than User, which then doesnt match the return type of my method. Is another map operator needed perhaps?

Comment: @Aardvark those are just typing errors in TS, you should change the `Observable<User>` for `Observable<Credentials>` at your function signature !